# Help understanding the proof of the definition of Big-Theta based on limits

Tags: big-o-notation

I was reading Kleinberg's and Tardo's book (especifically, [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321295358)) and, on page 38, these authors define the Big-Theta notation the following way:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)/g(n)$ exists and is equal to some number $c>0$. Then $f=\Theta(g)$.

Then, they provide a proof that connects the classic defition based on sets of functions to this definition based on the limit of the ratio of two functions. This proof goes as:

> We will use the fact that the limit exists and is positive to show that $f=O(g)$ and $f=\Omega(g)$, as required by the definition of $\Theta(\cdot)$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)/g(n)=c>0$, it follows from the definition of a limit that there is some $n_0$ beyond which the ratio is always between $c/2$ and $2c$. Thus, $f(n)\leq 2cg(n)$ for all $n\geq n_0$, which implies that $f=O(g)$; and $f\geq c/2\cdot g(n)$ for all $n\geq n_0$, which implies $f=\Omega(g)$. $\blacksquare$

However, I'm struggling to follow this proof; in particular, I fail to see how or why the authors chose the constants $c/2$ and $2c$ "from the definition of the limit" (as they say). I consulted Leithold's book on calculus ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9706131825)) and, on page 250, I found the following definition for infinite limits (translation is mine):

> Let $f$ be a function defined for all numbers within some open interval $(a,\infty)$. The limit of $f(x)$ when $x$ grows indefinitely is $L$, which is denoted as $\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)}=L$, if, for any $\varepsilon >0$ (no matter how small this number is), there exists a number $n>0$ such that: if $x>n$, then $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Applying this definition to Kleinberg's and Tardo's proof, I understand that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)/g(n)=c$ implies that, no matter what $\varepsilon$ I choose, there's always an $n_0$ beyond which $|f(n)/g(n)-c|<\varepsilon$ (in other words, the ratio $f(n)/g(n)$ differs from $c$ within any given margin $\varepsilon$). But then, I fail to see how this fact implies that "the ratio is always between $c/2$ and $2c$", as Kleinberg and Tardos claimed.

I think that the definition of infinite limits allows us to choose (at least in this particular case) any $\varepsilon$ that we find convenient, since $n_0$ will always exist no matter what we choose. Following this idea, I would suspect that Kleinberg and Tardos simply chose a value for $\varepsilon$ for which $|f(n)/g(n)-c|<\varepsilon$ would imply that $c/2\leq f(n)/g(n)\leq 2c$ is always true. However, I don't think such $\varepsilon$ can be chosen under these circumstances, since the distance from $c/2$ to $c$ is not the same as the distance from $c$ to $2c$.

Can somebody please help me understand what step I'm missing from this proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of the limit, for any $\epsilon$ we can always establish

$$c-\epsilon<\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}<c+\epsilon$$

by choosing $n$ sufficiently large.

In fact, the proof stops here, as this reads

$$c_0 g(n)\le f(n)\le c_1 g(n).$$

The author preferred to work with $\epsilon=\dfrac c2$ on the left and $\epsilon=c$ on the right (this is more "constructive"), but that does not make a big difference.

---

Technical note: $c_0$ must be positive, so we must choose $\epsilon<c$ on the left (hence the $\frac12$). There is no such constraint on the right, but the author might as well have kept the same $\epsilon$ for clarity.

---

The reciprocal is not true. As a counter-example, consider

$$f(n)=(2+\sin n)n.$$

We do have

$$n\le (2+\sin n)n\le 3n\implies f(n)=\Theta(n)$$ but the limit does not exist.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now. The authors chose two different values for $\varepsilon$ instead of just one. Sometimes I just forget about the most basic stuff, many thanks. Also, thank you for mentioning that the converse is not true, that's a good reference for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a few observations about Yves Daoust's answer. The relation
$$
(1)\qquad c-\varepsilon<\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}<c+\varepsilon
$$
can be esaily inferred by tracing $|f(n)/g(n)-c|<\varepsilon$ on the number line like so:

[image: Number line]

That is, $f(n)/g(n)$ can be any value in the interval $(c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)$. From there, as just explained in my question, we can choose a value for $\varepsilon$ that we find convenient.

My confusion was that the authors chose two different values for $\varepsilon$. This can be more esily seen by separating the relation (1) in two relations and working separately on them (this was explained by Yves Daoust in his/her answer), as so:
$$
(2) \qquad\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}-c<\varepsilon\\
(3) \qquad c-\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}<\varepsilon
$$

For (2), we can choose $\varepsilon=c$ and get the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}-c&<c\\
\therefore f(n)&<2c\cdot g(n)
\end{aligned}
$$
which satisfies the definition for $f=O(g)$ (remember that, no matter what value for $\varepsilon$ we choose, there always exists an $n_0$ for which $f(n)<2c\cdot g(n)$ is true for all $n\geq n_0$; this is by the definition of the limit that I stated in my question).

Finally, for (3), we can choose $\varepsilon=c/2$ and get the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
c-\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}&<c/2\\
\therefore (c/2)g(n)&<f(n)
\end{aligned}
$$
which satisfies the definition for $f=\Omega(g)$. Thus, since $f=O(g)$ and $f=\Omega(g)$, we conclude that $f=\Theta(g)$, finishing the proof.

Comment: Slight fix: every inequality has its own $n_0$. The claim holds when you take the maximum of the two.

Answer (score -1):

*If* the limit exists then f/g will be between c-eps and c+eps for every eps > 0 if n is large enough. The author chose eps=1/2 which is more than good enough to prove big-theta.

But big theta doesn’t require a limit. 2 + cos(n) is big-theta(1).